# Hardware accelerated OpenGL on VxWorks 5.5

Tags: opengl, driver, vxworks, mesa

I need to do hardware accelerated OpenGL rendering on VxWorks5.5 platform. After days of googling, I am confused about the following questions:

1. Stand alone Mesa3D can only do software rendering on VxWorks?( Provided that I ported Mesa3D to VxWorks)
2. Mesa3d combine with DRI can do hareware accelerated rendering on VxWorks? If so, Do I need an extra OpenGL hardware driver besides Mesa3d+DRI? (Mesa just provide gl APIs and DRI is the one which implement concrete hardware rendering, is that right?)
3. Are there any commercial solutions out there?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to upgrade your vxworks? You can refer to the documents to see if it meets your requirement

If yes, From VxWorks 6.9.3.3 onwards, Mesa driver is supported for Wind Media Library also. You can find the detail info in Wind River Media Library SDK Programmer’s Guide.

If you have upgraded to VxWorks 6.9.3 Update Pack 3 or above, you should have the mesa directory in the installation :

/components/windml-5.3/src/mesa-7.6.1

For more information on the mesa driver for Wind Media Library, please refer to the [Wind Media Library SDK Programmers Guide 5.3 Edition 3](https://ask.windriver.com/upfiles/14060681123667505.zip). Specifically Chapter 3 about building Media Library, under section 3.5.1 and Chapter 8 on OpenXX applicaitons.

[Wind Media Library SDK Programmers Guide 5.3 Edition 5](https://ask.windriver.com/upfiles/14060691146834311.zip)  has the information pertaining OpenGL ES1, OpenGL ES2, and Open VG supported only by the PowerVR drivers.